# Are Anges's Special Items miss-able?

Tags: xanadu-next

I've just gotten through Eternal Mage and back into Clover Ruins. to the west after clearing out all the monsters at a waterfall where one of those statues that upgrades your Guardian i find Anges waiting (after i enter another screen and return).

Just like before when she was waiting just south before the entrance to Eternal Mage (before the Salamander Fight) she can sell me Bones, Potions and a Special Item. the first time i got the Bone Carving Knife for 100G which is cheap enough. this time however her special item is some potion she's selling for 2,000G.

At the moment i only have a touch under 800G so i am think wether i should grind for some more G to get it or not. as such i am wondering, are the Special Items Angres sells miss-able? ie. if i find her somewhere else she'll have a different item and i can't get the previous item on sale?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one of the items is missable: **Superior Bone-Knife**

At the end of *Trechier Woods*, Agnes appears in a cutscene with a statue. If you leave the area without buying the knife from her, she never reappears there and you won't be able to buy it. **You only have one chance**. It's the *'special item'* dialog option, and she charges **400g**. She says something like *"I found a SUPER useful knife for carving bones."* or something, which is your only indication that it's better than the one she already sold you at the beginning of the game.

I missed it my first time because I was wearing the *Spectacles* to get through *Trechier Woods* since it illuminates the correct path. The *Spectacles* make all enemies invisible, but it ALSO makes NPCs invisible, and so it's easy to miss her if you had them equipped to navigate the woods. I had to reload an earlier save. Missing this knife also makes you unable to get the Silver Armor later, so it's not just one item you're missing, but two.

As for Agnes' other spawn locations, you can return to them at any time to buy the special item she sells at those specific locations (sometimes you may have to clear a room and re-enter it for her to be there.)